# Vim syntax highlighting for ARB templates (ActiveAdmin) is not working

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, activeadmin, vim-syntax-highlighting

When I open ARB template with Vim syntax highlighting is not working:

-app/views/admin/news/_show.html.arb

```
panel "#{t('active_admin.details', model: "News")}" do
  attributes_table_for news do
    row :id
    row :title
    row :description
    row :twitter_url do
      link_to(news.twitter_url, news.twitter_url, target: "_blank") if news.twitter_url
    end
#...
```

Everything is just black and white, it doesn't show colors

How to fix that?

Comment: What does `:setlocal ft? syntax?` show?

Comment: `filetype=` and `syntax=` soo, it is empty.

Comment: It means that you don't have any syntax script or any filetype-specific script for ARB. Did you search vim.org?

Comment: I think there isn't such thing. ARB templates are rarely used. I have searched vimscripts and didn't found anything useful. But I think that by setting all files `*.arb` to just use Ruby syntax, will be OK.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your ARB templates aren't recognized by Vim. To teach Vim to highlight them as *Ruby*, create a file `~/.vim/ftdetect/arb.vim` and insert the following command:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.arb setfiletype ruby
```

For more information, see `:help new-filetype`.

Comment: Thanks, the correct syntax is:

`autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.arb set filetype=ruby`

Comment: @TamVo: The `:setfiletype` is valid, too, and avoids re-assignment of a different filetype. If that doesn't work for you, that means that another detection is taking precedence.